# How to mount a folder to the docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

In my server, I have a mounted storage :

[image]

here is my docker compose file to deploy MySQL:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  mysqlslavedb1:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 22
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    volumes:
      - /mnt/storage/mysqlslavedb1:/var/lib/mysql
```

here is my /mnt/storage folder:

[image]

If I run the command and enter the container:

```
docker compose up -d
```

I can have the error:

```
mysqld: Can't change permissions of the file 'ca-key.pem' (Errcode: 1 - Operation not permitted)
[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
```

docker creates the mysqlslavedb1 by it self but still gets the error.

Answer (score 0):

first install latest version of docker compose via this commands :

```
pip3 install docker-compose
```

or may :

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

now you have to set previlages access into your docker compose yaml under restart :

```
privileged: true
```

finally try to make it up with this command :

```
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Don't forget to declare "-" between docker compose and sudo permission !
Hope to be useful.

Comment: `Don't forget to declare "-" between docker compose` not required anymore as Compose is now a part of Docker distribution